# Django ArrayField creating three Charfields within?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

It's my first time trying to pass in a field type within Django models.py where I can create a list within an arrayfield. For example I want to create..

```
neighborhood = Arrayfield(models.Charfield(max_length=100))
```

But within neighborhood I want to have the drop down choices of...

```
area = [Brooklyn, Manhattan, Queens]
```

How do I do this within models.py, is `area` suppose to be it's on class within my models.py? I am using Postgres SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `models.CharField` with choices. ([django docs reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices)).

For example,

```py
CHOICES = [("Brooklyn", "Brooklyn"), ("Manhattan", "Manhattan"), ("Queens", "Queens")]
neighborhood = models.CharField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        default="Brooklyn",
    )
```

Comment: I was really over thinking it before. Thank you